# How to add : "config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;" Extended ApplicationUser

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I want to add in : `config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;` to my startup code in .net core 2.2.

The example given by Microsoft shows how to do it for the stock standard identity user, but I have extended the user and it is now `ApplicationUser`.

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(               
    options => options.Stores.MaxLengthForKeys = 128
);
```

But in Microsoft example, it is like this (see below) which does not suit my needs...

```
   services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(config =>
    {
      config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
    })
```

How do I include this in my code using config ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(options =>
{
    options.Stores.MaxLengthForKeys = 128;
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
});
```